# Passing data to a jQuery-UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Often I have a table or a list, and I want to create an event when a given row is clicked, and do something specific to the clicked row.  To do so, I have been defining data() within click().  Sometimes I just send a piece of data and other times I send the entire row.

Is the way I am doing this the best way, or is there a better way?  Is it best to send just the required data to the dialog, or send the entire object over (i.e. row in my case) and extract data within the dialog?

Thanks

```
$("#someTable tbody").on("click", "a.doIt", function() {
    $("#dialog").data('id',$(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id')).dialog("open");
    //$("#dialog").data('id',$(this).parent().parent()).dialog("open");
    return false;
});
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open        : function() {
        alert($(this).data('id')+' is available.');
        //alert($(this).data('row').attr('data-id')+' is available.');
    },
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'CLOSE',
            "class"  : 'gray',
            click    : function() {
                alert($(this).data('id')+' is available.');
                //alert($(this).data('row').attr('data-id')+' is available.');
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]    
});


<table id="someTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="123"><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="doIt">aaa</a></td><td>bbb</td></tr>
        <tr data-id="321"><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="doIt">ccc</a></td><td>ddd</td></tr>
        <tr data-id="111"><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="doIt">eee</a></td><td>fff</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does the code work properly?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock.  Yes.  But if there is a de facto standard way of doing this, I would like to do it that way.

Comment: I only ask because I flagged this to be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com which is the better place for this question.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock.  Thanks.  I never heard of codereview.stackexchange.com before.  I will use it next time for these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data for ui-dialog like this

```
document.getElementById('dialog-modal').innerHTML = '<span style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px">'+str+'</span>';
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 120,
        modal: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

You can change the innerHTML of the id you want and then open the dialog box.

UPDATED:

```
$("#someTable tbody").on("click", "a.doIt", function() {
$("#dialog").html($(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id').html());

$("#dialog").dialog({
        height: 120,
        modal: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });});
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for the alternate approach.  Probably best to keep doing it the way I had been.  Agree?